# Delphi CnPack - Shortcut for Code formatting

Tags: delphi, plugins, keyboard-shortcuts

I have installed CnPack (https://www.cnpack.org) to get. At least, a little bit of the experience you get with VS Code. CnPack is a really great tool and I don't want to miss it, but it overwrites the default Shortcuts of Delphi RAD Studio. After Installation, I miss the Shortcut for automatic code formatting. Usually it is CTRL + D. I found that CnPack has also Code Formatting ability, but I could not find the manuals for it, and therefore I could not find the keyboard shortcuts for that. Any experience with that?

Comment: (Next time write full words, like "manual" instead of "_men+_".) And you did not even check [their forum](http://bbs.cnpack.org/viewthread.php?tid=144952&extra=page%3D4) to get ideas where keys could be reassigned?

Comment: Thanks for the Hint with men+ do not know how it gets there. But your Link did not help. I found that one too, but it is not what I was searching for. In This menu, there is no CTRL+D Shortcut.

Comment: Found it. The help says it is CTRL + W but it was not set. Under menu CnPack -> Code formatter -> Options I could set new keyboard Shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Menu `CnPack` -> `Code formatter` -> `Options` it is possible to set new Shortcodes.

There you can also delete the existing one without setting a new one if you don't use it anyway.